# Spreadtab and newcommand

Tags: spreadtab

I'm trying to achieve this kind of thing :

```
\newcommand{\test}[2]{#1 & :={#2} € & :={[-2,0] * [-1,0]} € \\}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|r|r|}}
@ Col 1 & @ Col 2 & @ Col 3 \\
\hline
\test{2}{50}
\test{3}{100}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{@ Total} & :={sum(c2:[0,-1])} € \\
\end{spreadtab}
```

This doesn't work and shows me formulas instead of result.

I understand formulas aren't processed because they are in the command, but I didn't found how to resolve it.

----- edited 5 month later -----

The accepted answer is a pretty good answer to the question I was asking, but after some time unable to really getting what I wanted, I let it go and came back later when I had time, with another technique, not using spreadtab at all (it's a good module, but not adapted to my case).

For those reading this question, there is my solution :

```latex
\newcounter{total}
\setcounter{total}{0}
\newcommand{\test}[2]{
    \addtocounter{total}{\fpeval{#1 * #2}}
    #1 & #2 € & {\fpeval{#1 * #2} €} \\
}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|r|r|}
Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 \\
\hline
\test{2}{50}
\test{3}{100}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Total} & \the\numexpr\value{total} € \\
\end{tabularx}
```

This is a longer solution than what I wanted, with "manual" formulas, but this works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Better? Answer

A variant that doesn't need you to put `\noexpand` everywhere, but expands only a defined set of macros (in the order you added those). The macros need to be expandable and expand in one step (so nothing that gets optional arguments and nothing too fancy, well if they need more they are still only expanded once). The macros which should be expanded can't be in any braced group as then they will not be found and not expanded.

Use `\AddXspreadtabMacro` on a macro that should be expanded in the body of `Xspreadtab`, you can also use `\RemXspreadtabMacro` to remove a macro from the list which should be expanded. Both `\Add...` and `\RemXspreadtabMacro` work on a local scope.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% will store the body of the spreadtab on which we're working
\tl_new:N \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl
% will store the macro names which should be expanded
\seq_new:N \l_guildem_expansion_seq
% used to signal that we should do another expansion loop for a macro
\bool_new:N \l__guildem_loop_bool
% add the macro to the list of macros which should be expanded
\NewDocumentCommand \AddXspreadtabMacro { m }
  {
    \seq_if_in:NnF \l_guildem_expansion_seq { #1 }
      {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_guildem_expansion_seq { #1 }
      }
  }
% remove a macro from the list
\NewDocumentCommand \RemXspreadtabMacro { m }
  {
    \seq_remove_all:Nn \l_guildem_expansion_seq { #1 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__guildem_sanitize_spreadtab_aux:w #1 \q_nil \q_stop
  {
    \tl_set:No \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl { \use_none:n #1 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__guildem_sanitize_spreadtab:
  {
    \exp_after:wN
    \__guildem_sanitize_spreadtab_aux:w \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl \q_stop
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__guildem_expand_macro:n #1
  {
    % check whether the macro is in the body of the spreadtab
    \tl_if_in:NnT \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl { #1 }
      {
        \bool_set_true:N \l__guildem_loop_bool
        % define a helper function that expands the macro
        \cs_set:Npn \__guildem_expand_macro_aux:w ##1 #1 ##2 \q_stop
          {
            \tl_set:Nn \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl { ##1 }
            \tl_put_right:No \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl { #1 ##2 }
          }
      }
    % \l__guildem_loop_bool is true as long as the macro is still contained in
    % the body and not yet expanded
    \bool_while_do:Nn \l__guildem_loop_bool
      {
        % call the helper macro that expands the macro
        \exp_after:wN
        \__guildem_expand_macro_aux:w \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl \q_stop
        % check whether there is another occurrence of macro in the body
        \tl_if_in:NnF \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl { #1 }
          { \bool_set_false:N \l__guildem_loop_bool }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__guildem_spreadtab:nn #1 #2
  {
    \begin{spreadtab}#1#2\end{spreadtab}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__guildem_spreadtab:nn { nV }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Xspreadtab}{O{} m b}
  {
    % adding \q_nil on both sides to not accidentally remove a group while later
    % parsing.
    \tl_set:Nn \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl { \q_nil #3 \q_nil }
    % step over the macros which should be expanded and expand those
    \seq_map_function:NN \l_guildem_expansion_seq \__guildem_expand_macro:n
    % remove the \q_nil from both ends
    \__guildem_sanitize_spreadtab:
    % output the spreadtab
    \__guildem_spreadtab:nV { [{#1}]{#2} } \l_guildem_spreadtab_tl
  }
  {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\test}[2]{#1 & :={#2} € & :={[-2,0] * [-1,0]} €}
\AddXspreadtabMacro\test

\begin{document}
\begin{Xspreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|r|r|}}
@ Col 1 & @ Col 2 & @ Col 3 \\
\hline
\test{2}{50} \\
\test{3}{100} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{@ Total} & :={sum(c2:[0,-1])} € \\
\end{Xspreadtab}
\end{document}
```

## Original Answer

The problem is, that `spreadtab` doesn't expand its contents before searching for formulas. You could (in theory) create an environment that works like `spreadtab` but expands its contents before forwarding it to `spreadtab`, though this would make it necessary to put `\noexpand` before every macro that shouldn't be expanded, so the input doesn't really get easier.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \Xspreadtab_expansion_helper:nn #1 #2 { #1 #2 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \Xspreadtab_expansion_helper:nn { nx }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Xspreadtab}{O{} m b}
  {
    \Xspreadtab_expansion_helper:nx { \begin{spreadtab}[{#1}]{#2} } { #3 }
    \end{spreadtab}
  }
  {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\test}[2]{#1 & :={#2} € & :={[-2,0] * [-1,0]} €}

\begin{document}
\begin{Xspreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|r|r|}}
@ Col 1 & @ Col 2 & @ Col 3 \noexpand\\
\noexpand\hline
\test{2}{50} \noexpand\\
\test{3}{100} \noexpand\\
\noexpand\hline
\noexpand\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{@ Total} & :={sum(c2:[0,-1])} € \noexpand\\
\end{Xspreadtab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse me for the answer time.
Thanks for your help. This is not a perfect answer, because noexpand use is not my idea of simplicity, but I understand that this solution is probably the only one available due to spreadtab mechanism.
So I will change my use case, to fit this limitation and allow me to use commands to fill a spreadtab.
This is why I mark your answer as an accepted answer :) Thanks !

Comment: @guildem I've build something better, see my edit.

Comment: unfortunately, something is wrong in your new example. "Evaluation results in mu
ltiple values" when compiled without changes, sum command is shown as text if I remove € sign after it. After some research, I found that the ":={}" term in the total line is not interpreted. if I replace it by a "\total" command, it will work. Same thing if I try to add a "/test" line raw equivalent directly on the Xspreadtab environment. So only the calculation into commands seems to be interpreted.

Comment: @guildem Is your LaTeX installation up to date? For me the results are fine in the second example using the latest version of TeX Live.

Comment: lastest version available on archlinux using gummi as editor. i'll try with manual compilation.

Comment: @guildem which version is your `spreadtab` package?

Comment: sorry I didn't answer to you, I change my tool to get what I wanted (professional need, no time to wait), but I have today a solution less automated, but also less "technical" that feets my needs. I edited the post to show how it works. Thank you for your time !